# Configuring S3 on Spinnaker with Helm

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I'm trying out Spinnaker and since we use Helm quite regularly I'm trying to deploy it using `stable/spinnaker` ( https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/spinnaker)

Running it with the default configuration works, no complaints at all. The issue comes when I try to replace Minio with S3. To do so I go to the values file and edit the following:

```
minio:
  enabled: false
```

and

```
s3:
  enabled: true
  bucket: "mybucketname"
  rootFolder: "front50"
  region: "eu-west-1"
  accessKey: "myaccesskey"
  secretKey: "mysecretkey"
```

However, `front50` is not happy. I'm getting an `UnknownHostException`.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.model.S3StorageService]: Factory method 's3StorageService' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: mybucket-dev.spinnaker-minio
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 134 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: mybucket-dev.spinnaker-minio
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5062) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5008) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1416) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.model.S3StorageService.ensureBucketExists(S3StorageService.java:75) ~[front50-s3.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.config.S3Config.s3StorageService(S3Config.java:57) ~[front50-s3.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.config.S3Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f80523e.CGLIB$s3StorageService$2(<generated>) ~[front50-s3.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.config.S3Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f80523e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5007d3c3.invoke(<generated>) ~[front50-s3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.config.S3Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f80523e.s3StorageService(<generated>) ~[front50-s3.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 135 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mybucket-dev.spinnaker-minio
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298) ~[na:na]
    at com.amazonaws.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:27) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.DelegatingDnsResolver.resolve(DelegatingDnsResolver.java:38) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy125.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1330) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.802.jar:na]
    ... 157 common frames omitted
```

My bucket is called `mybucket-dev` I don't understand where `.spinnaker-minio` is coming from.

I've also checked the `install-using-hal` pod logs:

```
hal --daemon-endpoint http://spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard:8064 config storage s3 edit --bucket mybucket-dev --root-folder front50 --region eu-west-1 --access-key-id mykey --secret-access-key
```

The bucket name is properly set there.

I've tried:

- Halyard: `1.32.0` Spinnaker `1.19.4`
- Halyard: `1.39.0` Spinnaker `1.22.1`

With the same result.

The `front50` Docker image is automatically set to:

```
gcr.io/spinnaker-marketplace/front50:0.25.1-20200831095512
```

The AWS permissions should be OK. Is there anything I'm missing on the config side?

Thanks

Comment: is this resolved for u? iam also struck in same issue

Comment: Nah, ended up dropping it. The chart didn't work for me.